# How to get Skype's indicator on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, indicator, skype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the Skype status icon back? (on panel/tray)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151112/how-do-i-get-the-skype-status-icon-back-on-panel-tray)

After upgrading to 12.04 (64bit), I've started installing the programs that I used to have on 10.04, one of them is skype.
Downloaded the .deb file from Skypes website and installed it using the Ubuntu software center.
However, when I launch skype, it doesnt add an indicator to the top menu like it used to, which means that when I click the 'x' on the program's window, it goes away, I cant reopen it, and I'm still logged in.

How can I get the indicator back?
Thank you